# Face id .Net Maui Plugin.Fingerprint

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a problem with Maui. I need to implement biometric authentication (face id on Ios Device), but the Plugin.Fingerprint package doesn't work (it's probably outdated). I am using .Net version 7.0.0. I have tried both instantiating the object as a singleton:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IFingerprint), CrossFingerprint.Current);
```

and injecting it

```
    private readonly IFingerprint fingerprint;

public loginView(loginViewModel _loginViewModel,
    IFingerprint _fingerprint)
```

Throws an error when creating the object:

```
This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly. You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.
```

Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Try out https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric, to which I have added .NET 8 support

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by installing the 3.0.0 beta version of the plugin.Fingerprint. You need to enable pre-releases